# How to exclude the last character from the below reg expression response

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am having the below text response I created a regular expression but I want to exclude the last character from the response.

**INPUT**:

```
href=\"admin_task_detail?rid=d652a3dd-fff0-4174-a065-5158298493af&tid=4947358c-9f5a-4174-8699-7fa12f9ac3c8&v=5ecb5743a92e7\" >T4947-C3C8<\/a>","@data-order":"T4947-C3C8"},
```

**Reg Exp which I tried**

```
tid=(.+?)\"
```

**Results:**

```
Match[1][0]=tid=4947358c-9f5a-4174-8699-7fa12f9ac3c8&v=5ecb5743a92e7\"
Match[1][1]=4947358c-9f5a-4174-8699-7fa12f9ac3c8&v=5ecb5743a92e7\
```

The slash symbol need to get excluded from the response.

Comment: Maybe: `tid=([^\\]*)`?

Comment: Try - `tid=(.+?)(.?)"`

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the backslash in the regex:

```
tid=(.+?)\\"
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/9PPy81/1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that you need this:

```
tid=4947358c-9f5a-4174-8699-7fa12f9ac3c8&v=5ecb5743a92e7
```

and not this:

```
tid=4947358c-9f5a-4174-8699-7fa12f9ac3c8
```

?

Because these `tid` and `v` are different parameters of the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and most probably you need only `tid`, not `v`.

In first case the relevant regular expression would be `tid=(.+?)\\`

[image]

In the second case you will need `tid=(.+?)&`

[image]

The tricky point is that backslash is a [meta character](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) so it needs to be escaped by the extra backslash.

In the majority of cases (like in your one) it's easier and better to use [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) where you don't need to deal with these regular expressions, it's sufficient to provide left and right boundaries in the plain text. Check out [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) article for more details.